# Should nuget clean up config files after doing transforms

Tags: nuget, thinktecture-ident-server, config-transformation

I'm developing a nuget package in order to pull my company's own **userValidation** and **claimsRepository** into the Thinktecture Identity Server.

I've changed how my config is stored to match how Thinktecture are doing it. (ie - connectionStrings & repositories config in their own files within a Configuration folder) I've done that so I can use config transforms.

The problem I'm having is that the **xdt** attributes (and xmlns on the root element) are left in the resulting config files. While this may not cause a problem it just seems a bit messy.

So, is that standard behaviour or is it a bug in nuget and non web/app.config file transforms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .transform files don't require the xdt attributes in the current version. See the documentation here: http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/configuration-file-and-source-code-transformations

Make sure the transform files are added to your project and their build action is set to "Content" rather than "None"